# How do I get my submit button to go to different pages based on a form score?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a website using java, to create a tallied form based on check-boxes, I have done that bit. However the part that I am having a problem with is the `submit` button - it needs to configure the score and take you to one of 6 other pages based on the score of the test. So, if a person get a score of 0-1, they are redirected to one page and if they get a score of 2-3, they get redirected to another page and so on. I have tried a ton of different things to accomplish this, but it ruins my java-script and my test won't work after that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fast.fonts.net/cssapi/731cabbe-df4e-4566-ac88-f64a4500c6b6.css"/>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pathway+Gothic+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:100,400,700,100italic,400italic,700italic"/>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
      item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }
  }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>

Window Cleaner <br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=window1>Ammonium Hydroxide<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=window2>Sodium Borate<br/>
<br><br>

Hand Soap<br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=handsoap1>Formaldehyde<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=handsoap2>Fragrance<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=handsoap3>Triclosan<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=handsoap4>DMDM Hydantoin<br/>
<br><br>

All Purpose Cleaner<br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=allpurpose1>Ammonium Hydroxide<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=allpurpose2>Triethanolamine<br/>
<br><br>

Lotion<br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=lotion1>Propylparaben<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=lotion2>Benzyl Alcohol<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=lotion3>Fragrance<br/>
<br><br>

Furniture Polish<br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=fpolish1>Naptha<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=fpolish1>Silicone Fluid<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=fpolish1>Sodium Borate<br/>
<br><br>

Laundry Detergent<br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=laundry1>Nonylphenol Ethoxylates <br/>
<input type=checkbox name=laundry2>Linear Alkylbenzene Sulfonate(LAS)<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=laundry3>Petroleum distillates <br/>
<br><br>

Fabric Softener<br><br> 

<input type=checkbox name=fabricsoftener1>Ethylenediaminetetraaceticacid  <br/>
<input type=checkbox name=fabricsoftener2>Ethyl acetate<br/>
<br><br>

Shampoo<br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=shampoo1>Sodium Laureth Sulfate<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=shampoo2>Fragrance<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=shampoo3>Benzyl Salicylate<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=shampoo4>DMDM Hydantoin<br/>
<br><br>

Sanitizer<br><br>   

<input type=checkbox name=sanitizer1>Sodium Hypochlorite<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=sanitizer2>Alcohol<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=sanitizer3>Fragrance<br/>
<br><br>

Aerosol Deodorizers<br><br> 

<input type=checkbox name=deodorizers1>Fragrance<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=deodorizers2>Sodium Borate<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=deodorizers3>Benzisothiazolinone<br/>
<br><br>

Floor Cleaner<br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=floorcleaner1>Sodium Salts<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=floorcleaner2>Methylisothiazolinone<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=floorcleaner3>Ethoxyethanol<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=floorcleaner4>Fragrance<br/>
<br><br>

Bleach<br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=bleach1>Chlorine<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=bleach2>Sodium Hypochlorite<br/>
<br><br>

Dishwasher Detergent<br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=dishwasher1>Diethanolamine<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=dishwasher2>Quaternium-15 <br/>
<input type=checkbox name=dishwasher3>Zinc Carbonate<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=dishwasher4>Sodium Hypochlorite<br/>
<br><br>

Spot Cleaner<br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=spotcleaner1>2-Butoxyethanol<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=spotcleaner2>Sodium Salts<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=spotcleaner3>Sodium Borate<br/>
<br><br>

Counter Cleaner<br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=countercleaner1>Mipa-Borate <br/>
<input type=checkbox name=countercleaner2>Ammonium Hydroxide<br/>
<br><br>

Body Wash<br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=bodywash1>Fragrance<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=bodywash2>DMDM Hydantoin<br/>
<input type=checkbox name=bodywash3>Propylparaben<br/>
<br><br>

Even More Dangerous Chemicals to look for <br><br>

<input type=checkbox name=a1>Hydrozincite<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=a2>Polyacrylates<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=a3>Antifoam<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=a4>Polyethylene Glycol<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=a5>Buffer<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=a6>Ethanolamine<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=a7>Glycol Ethers<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=a8>Atrazine<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=a9>Glutaral<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=a10>Alcohol Ethoxylates <br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=a11>Ethanolamine<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=a12>Petroleum<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=a13>Alumina<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=a14>Polysorbate-20 <br/><br>
<br>
<input type=checkbox name=b1>Ammonium Hydroxide<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=b2>Sodium Tripolyphosphate<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=b3>2-Butoxyethanol<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=b4>Myristalkonium Saccharinate<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=b5>Di-(Palm Carboxyethyl)<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=b6>Alcohol Alkoxylates<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=b7>Methoxydiglycol<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=b8>Poloxamer 124 <br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=b9>Benzalkonium Chlorides<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=b10>Hexoxyethanol<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=b11>Phosphates<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=b12>Methylisothiazolinone<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=b13>Silicon Compounds<br/><br>
<input type=checkbox name=b14>Triethanolamine<br/><br>

<BR>
<input type=button onclick="doIt(this.form)" value="SUBMIT">       

<BR><BR>      

<BR>YOUR FINAL HOUSEHOLD TOXICITY SCORE: <input size=2 type=text name=clicked value=0 onfocus=blur()>
</form>
<script>
function doIt(_f)
{
  var _countCK=0;
  var _countTL=0;
  for(var _obj = _f.firstChild; _obj ; _obj=_obj.nextSibling)
  {
    if(_obj.name!=undefined)
    {
      if(_obj.type=="checkbox")
      {
        _countTL++;
        if(_obj.checked)
          _countCK++;
      }
    }
  }
  _f.clicked.value=_countCK;
  _f.notclicked.value=0+_countTL-_countCK;
}
</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `action` of the form before it is submitted (inside your `doIt` click handler).

```
var f = document.getElementById('myForm'); // put an ID on your form tag :)
if(score <= 1) {
    f.action = '/one-page';
} else if(score <= 3) {
    f.action = '/another-page';
}
```

If you just want to redirect the browser and not actually submit the form to the specified page, use `window.location` instead of setting the form action:

```
window.location = '/one-page';
```